# Powershell and odp.net

Tags: powershell, odp.net

I want to extract results of the following query:

```
$Query=@"
select
j.session_recid, j.session_stamp,
to_char(j.start_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') start_time,
to_char(j.end_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') end_time,
(j.output_bytes/1024/1024) output_mbytes, j.status, j.input_type,
decode(to_char(j.start_time, 'd'),1,'Sunday',2,'Monday',3,'Tuesday',4,'Wednesday',5,'Thursday',6,'Friday',7,'Saturday') dow,
j.elapsed_seconds,j.time_taken_display,x.cf,x.df,x.i0,x.i1,x.l,
ro.inst_id output_instance
from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS j
left outer join (select
d.session_recid, d.session_stamp,
sum(case when d.controlfile_included = 'YES' then d.pieces else 0 end) CF,
sum(case when d.controlfile_included = 'NO'
and d.backup_type'||'d.incremental_level = 'D' then d.pieces else 0 end) DF,
sum(case when d.backup_type'||'d.incremental_level = 'D0' then d.pieces else 0 end) I0,
sum(case when d.backup_type'||'d.incremental_level = 'I1' then d.pieces else 0 end) I1,
sum(case when d.backup_type = 'L' then d.pieces else 0 end) L
from  V$BACKUP_SET_DETAILS d
join V$BACKUP_SET s on s.set_stamp = d.set_stamp
and s.set_count = d.set_count
where s.input_file_scan_only = 'NO'
group by d.session_recid, d.session_stamp) x
on x.session_recid = j.session_recid
and x.session_stamp = j.session_stamp
left outer join (select o.session_recid, o.session_stamp, min(inst_id) inst_id
from GV$RMAN_OUTPUT o
group by o.session_recid, o.session_stamp) ro
on ro.session_recid = j.session_recid
and ro.session_stamp = j.session_stamp
where j.start_time > trunc(sysdate)-8
order by j.start_time
"@

$conString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXXXXXX)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXXXXXX)));User Id=system;Password=XXXXXXXX;";

$Connection=New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($conString) ;
Try {
$Connection.Open() ;
}
Catch {
write-host "Unable to open connection to Oracle DB" ;
}

$Command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($Query,$connection);

$Result = $Command.ExecuteReader();
```

The query works fine in sqlplus, TOAD etc.
However I get

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator"
At D:\Oradba\Scripts\Test-odp.ps1:162 char:33
+ $Result = $Command.ExecuteReader <<<< ();
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `$Query` string variable includes $ signs which Powershell is trying to interpret as a variable. Use the single quote form instead:

```
$Query=@'
#Your query
'@
```

Or escape the $s with a back tick like so:

```
GV`$RMAN_OUTPUT
```